# How to extend Laravel's basic route resource in Laravel 6?

Tags: laravel, laravel-routing, laravel-6

I'm using Laravel as an API with many endpoints and many controllers. I'm using `Route::resource()` method to define REST endpoints, but in most cases I need to add one more endpoint and now my code is looking like this:

```php
Route::get('product/list', 'ProductController@all');
Route::resource('product', 'ProductController');

Route::get('property/list', 'PropertyController@all');
Route::resource('property', 'PropertyController');

Route::get('customer/list', 'CustomerController@all');
Route::resource('customer', 'CustomerController');
```

...and this sample keeps coming up, over and over again. I think there needs to be a practical and better way to define this `{resource}/list` URI in one place. Now I need to repeat this sample:

`Route::get('{resource}/list', 'NameOfController@all');`

Is there a better solution to define this endpoint only once and be available in every controllers? Can I avoid somehow the repetition?

Comment: you could extend your own resource registrar that you can call to register the resource with your extra needed route

Comment: @lagbox : can you give me a sample code in an answer?

Comment: the posted answer covers it ... if you find you don't need the `list` endpoint for a particular resource use `except` to not register it `Route::resource('something', 'controller')->except('list');` ... you could also not bind the class and get an instance of your version of the registrar and use it directly ... depends what you want to do

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you take a look at the `resource` method in the `Illuminate\Routing\Router` class, you are going to see this:

```
if ($this->container && $this->container->bound(ResourceRegistrar::class)) {
    $registrar = $this->container->make(ResourceRegistrar::class);
} else {
    $registrar = new ResourceRegistrar($this);
}
```

Which means you can bind a `ResourceRegistrar` to overwrite the default one provided by Laravel. Therefore, to achieve what you want, you could first make a new class, for instance, `app/ResourceRegistrar.php`, which would extends the `Illuminate\Routing\ResourceRegistrar` and add a default `'list'`:

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Routing\ResourceRegistrar as BaseResourceRegistrar;

class ResourceRegistrar extends BaseResourceRegistrar
{
    protected $resourceDefaults = [
        'index', 'create', 'store', 'show', 'edit', 'update', 'destroy', 'list',
    ];

    /**
     * Add the list method for a resourceful route.
     *
     * @param  string  $name
     * @param  string  $base
     * @param  string  $controller
     * @param  array   $options
     * @return \Illuminate\Routing\Route
     */
    public function addResourceList($name, $base, $controller, $options)
    {
        $uri = $this->getResourceUri($name).'/all';

        $action = $this->getResourceAction($name, $controller, 'list', $options);

        return $this->router->get($uri, $action);
    }
}
```

And then, you can simply bind the registrar in your `AppServiceProvider`:

```
<?php

namespace App\Providers;

use App\ResourceRegistrar;
use Illuminate\Routing\Router;
use Illuminate\Routing\ResourceRegistrar as BaseResourceRegistrar;
use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;

class AppServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    public function boot()
    {
        $this->app->bind(BaseResourceRegistrar::class, ResourceRegistrar::class);
    }
}
```

And you can register your route like you used to without adding the extra line:

```
Route::resource('product', 'ProductController');
Route::resource('property', 'PropertyController');
Route::resource('customer', 'CustomerController');
```

Then if you run the `php artisan route:list`, you should see the `{resource}/list` route.

Comment: Is it possible to use this with `Route::apiResource()`? I can't figure out what is needed to make it work.

Comment: can you explain why ``app()->bind(BaseResourceRegistrar::class, function () {
            return new ResourceRegistrar(app()->make(Router::class));
        });`` 
not ``        $this->app->bind(BaseResourceRegistrar::class, ResourceRegistrar::class);`` 
Trying to understand the differnce here. Both seemed to work. and the Second way looks handy

Comment: @GayanKavirathne I've updated the answer to use `$this->app` instead. It has no different, using `app()` is simply referring to the [helper](https://laravel.com/docs/master/helpers#method-app) method.

Comment: My point was, 
Why should we instatiate the ResourceRegister with app as a parameter. For me it looks like we are re creating the app related configurations here. I'm suggesting this. 
``$this->app->bind(BaseResourceRegistrar::class, ResourceRegistrar::class);``
We just pass the abstract and concrete classes to the bind method, without instantiating

Comment: Also, if you can add a fair warning about the order of values in $resourceDefaults array that would be a huge favor for any new reader. I added a delete method massDelete. At was consumed by the destroy method all the time. Since the default delete method was like /product/{product} and my new route is like /product/massDelete, then it was consumed by destroy getting masDestroy as a parameter. 
Once again thanks for the work you have done here.

Comment: @Luciano did you find a way to do this for apiResrouce?

Comment: @AfzalAli No. In fact, I've stopped using route resources since I had to implement policies and explicit model bindings on most of my routes, therefore I had to define all my routes manually.

Answer (score 2):

I made it. You'll need to extend the registrar

## 1/2 Create Router class

```php
# I made mine in app/Overrides/Router.php
<?php

namespace App\Overrides;

use Illuminate\Routing\Router as BaseRouter;

class Router extends BaseRouter
{
    // You can call it however you want. These are the params you need to pass the original resource() method.
    public function listResource($name, $controller, array $options = [])
    {
        // What make a get route and then a normal resource route you'll be able to call optional methods on.
        $this->get($name.'/all', $controller.'@all')->name($name.'.all');
        return $this->resource($name, $controller, $options);
    }   
}
```

## 2/2 Bind it in bootstrap/app.php

```php
$app->singleton('router', function ($app) {
    return new \App\Overrides\Router($app['events'], $app);
});
```

## And you're done.

Now for the example:

```php
Route::listResource('users', 'UserController');
```

```
> php artisan r:l
+--------+-----------+----------------------+---------------+---------------------------------------------+--------------+
| Domain | Method    | URI                  | Name          | Action                                      | Middleware   |
+--------+-----------+----------------------+---------------+---------------------------------------------+--------------+
|        | GET|HEAD  | users                | users.index   | App\Http\Controllers\UserController@index   | web          |
|        | POST      | users                | users.store   | App\Http\Controllers\UserController@store   | web          |
|        | GET|HEAD  | users/create         | users.create  | App\Http\Controllers\UserController@create  | web          |
|        | GET|HEAD  | users/list           | users.list    | App\Http\Controllers\UserController@all     | web          |
|        | GET|HEAD  | users/{user}         | users.show    | App\Http\Controllers\UserController@show    | web          |
|        | PUT|PATCH | users/{user}         | users.update  | App\Http\Controllers\UserController@update  | web          |
|        | DELETE    | users/{user}         | users.destroy | App\Http\Controllers\UserController@destroy | web          |
|        | GET|HEAD  | users/{user}/edit    | users.edit    | App\Http\Controllers\UserController@edit    | web          |
+--------+-----------+----------------------+---------------+---------------------------------------------+--------------+
```